# MPI and Segmentation Faults

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, mpi, subroutine

Alright so this program is meant to simulate a solar system by semi-randomly generating a star, semi-randomly generating planets around the star, simulating the passing of time (using MPI to spread out the computational load), and determining habitability of resulting planets. I should have it commented for readability.

I am however having a problem with getting MPI working. As far as I can tell I'm doing something wrong that prevents it from initializing properly. Here's the errors I get.

```
OrbitPlus.cpp:323:50: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char**’ [-fpermissive]
     system1 = Time( system, n , dt , argc, **argv);
                                                  ^
OrbitPlus.cpp:191:33: error:   initializing argument 5 of ‘std::vector<std::vector<float> > Time(std::vector<std::vector<float> >, int, float, int, char**)’ [-fpermissive]
 std::vector<std::vector<float>> Time( std::vector<std::vector<float>> system , int n, float dt, int argc, char **argv){
                                 ^
```

I do find it interesting that both errors are considered fpermissive errors if when I compile it with -
`mpic++ -std=c++11 -o OrbitPlus OrbitPlus.cpp`

So it seems if I was feeling adventurous I could just run the code with -fpermissive option and roll the dice, but I don't feel like being so brave. Clearly the errors are related to each other.

Here's my code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

#include "mpi.h"

double MyRandom(){

  //////////////////////////
  //Random Number Generator
  //Returns number between 0-99
  //////////////////////////

  double y = 0;
  unsigned seed = time(0);
  std::srand(seed);
  uint64_t x = std::rand();

  x ^= x << 13;
  x ^= x >> 7;
  x ^= x << 17;

  x = (1070739 * x) % 2199023255530;
  y = x / 21990232555.31 ;
  return y;
}
////////////////////////

///////////////////////
std::tuple< char , float , float , float , int > Star(){

  ////////////////////////////
  //Star will generate a Star
  //Randomly or User Selected
  //Class, Luminosity, Probability, Radius, Mass, Temperature
  //Stars always take up 99% of the mass of the system.
  ///////////////////////////

  char Class;
  int choice = 8;
  float L, R, M, T;
  double y = 4;
  std::tuple< char , float , float , float , float > star( Class , L  , R , M , T) ;
  std::cout << "Select Star Class (OBAFGKM) or Select 8 for Random" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "1 = O, 2 = B, 3 = A, 4 = F, 5 = G, 6 = K, 7 = M : ";
  std::cin >> choice;
  if ( choice == 8 ) {
    y = MyRandom();
    if (y <= 0.003) choice = 1;
    if ((y > 0.003) && (y <= 0.133)) choice = 2;
    if ((y > 0.133) && (y <= 0.733)) choice = 3;
    if ((y > 0.733) && (y <= 3.733)) choice = 4;
    if ((y > 3.733) && (y <= 11.333)) choice = 5;
    if ((y > 11.333) && (y <= 23.433)) choice = 6;
    else choice = 7;
  }

  if (choice == 1) {
    Class = 'O';
    L = 30000;
    R = 0.0307;
    M = 16;
    T = 30000;
  }

  if (choice == 2) {
    Class = 'B';
    L = 15000;
    R = 0.0195;
    M = 9;
    T = 20000;
  }

  if (choice == 3) {
    Class = 'A';
    L = 15;
    R = 0.00744;
    M = 1.7;
    T = 8700;
  }

  if (choice == 4) {
    Class = 'F';
    L = 3.25;
    R = 0.00488;
    M = 1.2;
    T = 6750;
  }

  if (choice == 5) {
    Class = 'G';
    L = 1;
    R = 0.00465;
    M = 1;
    T = 5700;
  }

  if (choice == 6) {
    Class = 'K';
    L = 0.34;
    R = 0.00356;
    M = 0.62;
    T = 4450;
  }

  if (choice == 7) {
    Class = 'M';
    L = 0.08;
    R = 0.00326;
    M = 0.26;
    T = 3000;
  }

  return star;
}
////////////

///////////
std::vector< std::vector<float> > Planet( float L, float R, float M, int T, int n){

///////////////////////////
//Planet generates the Planets
//Random 1 - 10, Random distribution 0.06 - 6 JAU unless specified by User
//Frost line Calculated, First Planet after Frost line is the Jupiter
//The Jupiter will have the most mass of all Jovian worlds
//Otherwise divided into Jovian and Terrestrial Worlds, Random Masses within groups
//Also calculates if a planet is in the Habitable Zone
////////////////////////////

float frostline, innerCHZ, outerCHZ;
float a = 0.06; // a - albedo
float m = M / 100; //Mass of the Jupiter always 1/100th mass of the Star.
std::vector<float> sys;
std::vector<std::vector <float>> system;

for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
  sys.push_back( MyRandom()/10 * 3 ) ; //Distances in terms of Sol AU
                         }
  sort(sys.begin(), sys.end() );
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    system[i].push_back(sys[i]);
    system[i].push_back(0); //system[i][0] is x, system[i][1] is y
}

frostline = (0.6 * T / 150) * (0.6 * T/150) * R / sqrt(1 - a);
innerCHZ = sqrt(L / 1.1);
outerCHZ = sqrt(L / 0.53);

for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
  if (system[i][0] <= frostline) {
    float tmass = m * 0.0003 * MyRandom();
    system[i].push_back(tmass) ; //system[i][2] is mass, [3] is marker for the Jupiter
    system[i].push_back(0) ;
  }

  if ((system[i][0] >= frostline) && (system[i-1][0] < frostline)){
      system[i].push_back(m) ;
      float J = 1;
      system[i].push_back(J) ;
  }

  if ((system[i][0] >= frostline) && (system[i-1][0] >= frostline)) {
      float jmass = m * 0.01 * MyRandom();
      system[i].push_back(jmass) ;
      system[i].push_back(0) ;
  }

  if ((system[i][0] >= innerCHZ) && (system[i][0] <= outerCHZ)){
      float H = 1;
      system[i].push_back(H);
  }
  else system[i].push_back(0); //[4] is habitable marker

  }

  return system;
}
////////////

////////////
std::vector<std::vector<float>> Time( std::vector<std::vector<float>> system , int n, float dt, int argc, char **argv){

  #define ASIZE 3 //Setup
  int MPI_Init(int *argc, char ***argv);
  int rank, numtasks = n, namelen, rc;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init( &argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

  rc = MPI_Bcast(&system, ASIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Master
  // Broadcast computed initial values to all other processes

  if (rc != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops! An error occurred in MPI_Bcast()\n");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
  }

  //Slaves
  const float pi = 4 * atan(1.0);
  const float G = 6.67 * pow(10,-11);
  float a_x, a_y;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
    if (rank != i){
      a_x = G * system[i][2] * (system[i][0]-system[rank][0]) / ((system[i][0]-system[rank][0]) * (system[i][0]-system[rank][0]));
      a_y = G * system[i][2] * (system[i][1]-system[rank][1]) / ((system[i][1]-system[rank][1]) * (system[i][1]-system[rank][1]));
    }
    if (rank == i){
      a_x = G * system[i][2] * 100 * system[i][0] / (system[i][0] * system[i][0]);
      a_y = G * system[i][2] * 100 * system[i][1] / (system[i][1] * system[i][1]);
    }
    a_x += a_x;
    a_y += a_y;
  }

  for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
    system[i][0] += system[i][5] * dt + 0.5 * a_x * dt * dt;
    system[i][1] += system[i][6] * dt + 0.5 * a_y * dt * dt;
    system[i][5] += a_x * dt;
    system[i][6] += a_y * dt;
  }

  for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<i ; j++){
      if (system[j][0] == 0 && system[j][1] == 0){
    system.erase(system.begin() + j);
      } // crash into star
      if (system[j][0] == system[i][0] && system[j][1] == system[i][1]){
    system[i][2] += system[j][2];
    system.erase(system.begin() + j);
      } // planet crash
    } //check co-ordinates
  } // planet destroy loop

  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    if (sqrt(system[i][0]*system[i][0] + system[i][1]*system[i][1]) >= 60) system.erase(system.begin() + i);
  }

  //Send results back to the first process
  if (rank != 0){// All processes except the one of rank 0
    MPI_Send(&system, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  else {
    for (int j = 1; j < numtasks; j++) {
      MPI_Recv(&system, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1,
           MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
  }

  MPI_Finalize();

  ///////////////////////////
  //Time advances the solar system.
  //Plots the Orbits
  //Uses MPI to spread it's calculations.
  ///////////////////////////

  return system;
}
////////////

////////////
std::vector<bool> FinalCheck( std::vector<std::vector<float>> system, std::vector<bool> Water, int n){

///////////////////////////
//Final Checks
//Reports if a Planet spent the whole Time in the Habitable Zone
///////////////////////////

for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
  if (system[i][4] == 1.0) Water.push_back(true);
  else Water.push_back(false);
  }
return Water;
}
////////////

////////////
int main(int argc, char** argv){

  char Class;
  float L, R, M, T;

  std::tuple< char , float , float , float , float > star( Class , L , R , M , T );
  star = Star();

  int n = MyRandom()/10 + 1;

  std::vector<std::vector <float>> system ;
  std::vector<std::vector <float>> system1 ;
  system = Planet( L , R , M, T, n);

  float G = 6.67 * pow(10,-11), pi = 4 * atan(1.0), dt;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (system[i][3] == 1){
      dt = 2 * pi * .01 * pow(system[i][0] * 1.5 * pow(10,8), 1.5) / sqrt(G * M * 2 * pow(10,30));
    }
    system[i].push_back(0.0); //system[i][5] is speed in x-axis                                                                                                                                
    system[i].push_back( sqrt(6.67 * pow(10,-11) * 2 * pow(10,30) * M / system[i][0])); //system[i][6] is speed in y-axis                                                                      
  }

  std::ofstream Finder;
  std::ofstream Report;
  Finder.open("plotdata.dat");
  Report.open("report.txt");
  Finder << "# Plot Co-ordinates" << std::endl;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    system1 = Time( system, n , dt , argc, argv);
    for (int j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
      Finder << "[color " << j << "] " << system[j][0] << " " << system[j][1] << std::endl;
      if((system[j][4] == 1.0) && ( (sqrt(system[j][0] * system[j][0] + system[j][1] * system[j][1]) < sqrt(L / 1.1) ) || ((sqrt(system[j][0] * system[j][0] + system[j][1] * system[j][1]) > sqrt(L / 0.53)) ))) system[j][4] = 0.0;
    }
    system = system1;
  }
  Finder.close();
  int m;
  m = system.size()/system[0].size();

  std::vector<bool> Water;
  Water = FinalCheck( system, Water, n);

  //Report
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    Report << "Planet " << i << "ends up at" << system[i][0] << " and " << system[i][1] << "has mass " << system[i][2] ;
    if (system[i][3] == 1) Report << ", which is the 'Jupiter' of the system." ;
    if (system[i][4] == 1) Report << ", which can have liquid water on the surface." ;
  }
  Report.close();
  ///////////////////////////
  //Report cleans everything up and gives the results
  //Shows the plot, lists the Planets
  //Reports the Positions and Masses of all Planets
  //Reports which was the Jupiter and which if any were Habitable
  //////////////////////////
  return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts the gurus here have would be appreciated, especially with getting rid of those -fpermissive errors.

EDIT 1 - Code as presented will now completely compile - but will return a Segmentation fault during the Star routine. After the user inputs the star type but before it actually makes a star as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a Minimal Reproducible Example. That said, if `Time` takes in a `char **` why do you dereference `argv`?

Comment: Never heard the term 'Minimal Reproducible Example' before, honestly. But Time and main are the only parts that matter for this question, I can edit out the rest if that's what you want.

For argv, MPI appears to require it. Message Passing Interface doesn't do a whole lot with the arguments taken in as far as I can tell but it does need them.

Comment: [MRE Info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What I'm saying is, `Time`'s last parameter is `char **`. You have `argv` which is already `char **`, but, you pass it by dereferencing it (`**argv`), which then turns it into a `char`. You probably just want to pass `argv`, as in: `system1 = Time( system, n , dt , argc, argv)`

Comment: I think it is actually MRE to still be compileable, there's quite a bit to this project.

That did work though, in the sense that the code does completely compile. It does however now give me a Segmentation Fault. Thank you though.

Comment: `MPI_Init()` expects `&argc` and `&argv` as parameters, so you might want to revamp your functions to pass these arguments to `Time`. FWIW, if you are sure your implementation is not using these values, and you will never use an implementation that does, then you can simply `MPI_Init(NULL, NULL)` even if I do encourage you to write portable code.

Comment: you need to allocate your data in contiguous memory, and you might want to learn about `MPI_Gather()`.

Comment: Creating an MRE is an essential part of asking a good question. First, you are distilling the problem down to a manageable chunk of code and no one has to look through a wall of code to figure out what's going on. Also, often you yourself may discover the answer to your question while preparing the MRE. In your case, an MRE is simply to try and initialise MPI multiple times in a loop and to broadcast, or generally use in any MPI data transfer primitive, a vector of vectors - none of this works.

Comment: So an MRE is a recreation of the code that -
A.) Compiles
B.) Contains at least the parts I'm asking about?

Comment: ideally it should contains nothing more than the parts you are asking about, but enough to evidence your issue.